# how to make a type with keys as values from another type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a object

```
const navigatorNames: NavigatorNamesType = {
    homeNavigation: 'HomeNavigation',
    authNavigation: 'AuthNavigation'
}
```

where type is

```
 type NavigatorNamesType = {
    homeNavigation: 'HomeNavigation',
    authNavigation: 'AuthNavigation'
}
```

all I want is to create another type which is like

```
type NewType={
'HomeNavigation':undefined;
'AuthNavigation':undefined;
}
```

but this type should be dynamic in sense tenter code herehat if another key value is added in navigatorNames and NavigatorNamesTypes then NewType should automatically get update with that value as key and type as undefined.

Comment: Use a record and map over its values: `type NewType = Record<NavigatorNamesType[keyof NavigatorNamesType], undefined>;`

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches here: using record or enums(this is most restrictive and doesn't let you do too much fancy stuff). Using `enum` for your first type and then your `NewType` should be a mapped object type, something like this:

```
enum NavigatorNamesType {
    homeNavigation = 'HomeNavigation',
    authNavigation = 'AuthNavigation',
};

type NewType = {
    [key in  NavigatorNamesType]: undefined;
};

let A: NewType = {
    [NavigatorNamesType.authNavigation]: undefined,
    [NavigatorNamesType.homeNavigation]: undefined
}
// Or
let B: NewType = {AuthNavigation: undefined, HomeNavigation: undefined};
```

so you just need to add more values to your enum.
Using Record as @hhearts mentioned is another approach (notice I will still use an enum for the first type as it matches the restriction of using string | number| symbol for the key type an it seems more natural ;) ) and then it looks something like this:

```
enum NavigatorNamesType {
    homeNavigation = 'HomeNavigation',
    authNavigation = 'AuthNavigation',
};

let A: Record<NavigatorNamesType, undefined> = {AuthNavigation: undefined, HomeNavigation: undefined};
```